# Pivot column entries into a comma separated list in a single row for distinct adjacent column?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
SELECT Parent, Child FROM Daycare_Contacts
GROUP BY Parent, Child;
```

Returns a result set like

```
Parent     Child
Bob        Brett
Bob        Cindy
Bob        John
Alice      Pierre
Alice      John
```

I would like it to return children as a comma separated list with the distinct parent as the adjacent column. Like so:

```
Parent     Child
Bob        Brett, Cindy, John
Alice      Pierre, John
```

If it can be done in LINQ, I'd be open to that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can return a comma separated data from T-SQL.

For this goal you need to use [FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) command.

You can review details [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/05/sql-server-group-by-rows-and-columns-using-xml-path-efficient-concating-trick/).

Please check next T-SQL script:

```
DECLARE @Daycare_Contacts TABLE
(
    Parent VARCHAR(100),
    Child  VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Daycare_Contacts
VALUES ('Bob', 'Brett'), ('Bob', 'Cindy'), ('Bob', 'John'), ('Alice', 'Pierre'), ('Alice', 'John')

SELECT 
    Parent,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Child AS 'text()' FROM @Daycare_Contacts t WHERE t.PArent = dc.Parent FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Childs
FROM @Daycare_Contacts dc
GROUP BY Parent;
```

Result:

```
Parent    Childs
--------------------------
Alice     Pierre, John
Bob       Brett, Cindy, John
```

2) Also you can use LINQ.

You need to use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Examples and details are [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea).

My fiddle: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ZyGUC)

C# code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string Parent { get; set; }
        public string Child { get; set; }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        var datas = new List<SomeClass>
        {
            new SomeClass{ Parent = "Bob", Child = "Brett" },
            new SomeClass{ Parent = "Bob", Child = "Cindy" },
            new SomeClass{ Parent = "Bob", Child = "John" },
            new SomeClass{ Parent = "Alice", Child = "Pierre" },
            new SomeClass{ Parent = "Alice", Child = "John" }
        };

        var groups = datas.GroupBy(n => n.Parent)
            .Select(n => new
            {
                Parent = n.Key,
                Childs = string.Join(",", n.Select(i => i.Child))
            })
            .ToList();

        var result = string.Join("\n", groups);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already used within your SQL query - you can also use `GroupBy` in Linq.

---

For example you have a class for the received data like:

```
public class ReceivedDataObject
{
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string Child { get; set; }
}
```

and a collection containing all received elements like

```
var receivedData = new List<ReceivedDataObject>
{
    new ReceivedDataObject { Parent = "Bob", Child = "Brett" },
    new ReceivedDataObject { Parent = "Bob", Child = "Cindy" },
    new ReceivedDataObject { Parent = "Bob", Child = "John" },
    new ReceivedDataObject { Parent = "Alice", Child = "Pierre" },
    new ReceivedDataObject { Parent = "Alice", Child = "John" }
};
```

---

Now you can use `GroupBy` to group your received objects by the `Parent` property.

```
var groupData = receivedData.GroupBy(rd => rd.Parent);
```

---

For the output of the result you can use

```
foreach(var group in groupData)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key}: {string.Join(", ", group.Select(p => p.Child))}");
}

// Output
// Bob: Brett, Cindy, John
// Alice: Pierre, John
```

or as a new list of items:

```
var result = new List<ReceivedDataObject>();
foreach(var group in groupData)
{
    result.Add(new ReceivedDataObject() { Parent = group.Key, Child = string.Join(", ", group.Select(p => p.Child)) } );
}
```